# How to replace text with regex on PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have a text like "MASTER_LECTURE.NAME" so want to replace *MASTER_LECTURE* with space or another string. how to do that on regex php?

*i'm very newbie for REGEX. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with regular expression or simple string function

```
$string = 'MASTER_LECTURE.NAME';

$string_replace = 'MASTER_LECTURE';

// Regular expression
preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($string_replace).'/is', '', $string);

// String function
$string = str_replace($string_replace, '', $string);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: nice @delphist. Can you show me the pattern when word MASTER_LECTURE will dynamic depend on string that we submit?

Answer (score 1):

if you are only replacing a string and not a pattern you can use str_replace

Comment: you do not need a formula. Its just str_replace($search,$replace, $subject).  if its really a word and not a patter you should use this since its lighter

Comment: i need the pattern because the words will by dinamic.